# IIS returning plain Forbidden response. No HTTP code

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I'm running a ServiceStack application on IIS. My regular services work fine and have not had any problems with permissions.

My new project involves providing generated pdfs. I gave IIS_IUSRS read/write permissions to the Temp directory under my app directory. I also allow non SSL connections to this directory. When I browse to the file which ServiceStack is supposed to automatically serve up (eg. http://ryublalblah.com/Temp/201310171723337631.pdf ) I get this:

```
Forbidden


Request.HttpMethod: GET
Request.PathInfo: 
Request.QueryString: 
Request.RawUrl: /ryublalblah/Temp/201310171723337631.pdf
App.IsIntegratedPipeline: True
App.WebHostPhysicalPath: C:\inetpub\ryublalblah
App.WebHostRootFileNames: [global.asax,global.asax.cs,web.config,bin,temp]
```

Now this doesn't look like a ServiceStack error message, more like IIS, but I'm not certain as to how to get to the bottom of this. Authorization settings are Allow All.

Comment: Doesn't look like IIS either, what does the entry is the IIS http log says for such a request, what is the sub status, right next to the 403?

Comment: @PeterHahndorf I get this "2013-10-18 17:54:56 233.155.28.12 GET /ryublahblah/Temp/201310171723337631.pdf - 80 - 233.155.28.12 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/5.0) 403 0 0 202", are further diagnostics I can perform?

Comment: hmm, the sub-status is 0, which is not helpful. I would run Process Monitor (sysinternals.com) to see whether there are any Access Denied problems on the file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with ServiceStack 3.9.70. I created a new project hosted at the root of an IIS application. Turns out the problem was caused by the following line in the `AppHost` configuration

```
config.ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "";  // Results in forbidden
```

I had copied it from another project where ServiceStack was hosted in a subfolder:

```
config.ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "api";  // subfolder: WORKS
config.ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = null;   // root: WORKS
```